# Trouble on using AJAX forms

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.1.1 and the jquery-rails 1.0.16 gem. I have an issue on using a form with `:remote => true`.

In my view file I have:

```
<%= form_for(@user, :url => user_path(@user), :remote => true) do |f| %>
  ...

  <%= f.submit "Update" %>
<% end %>
```

When I click on the `Update` button and I inspect the *Firebug Console*, I see that two AJAX HTTP requests are performed instead of one as well as it should be. The same problem happens for all forms in my application that are using `:remote => true`.

**What could be the problem? How to fix it?**

---

*Note*: If I inspect the DOM it seems that in the current page I do not have duplicate of HTML\CSS `id` values.

*P.S. I*: I tried to use different browsers and clear them cache but the problem still occurs.

*P.S. II*: The problem occurs in development mode in localhost (on my local machine). I have not tried yet if it happens in production mode on the remote machine.

---

**UPDATE I**

In my `application.js` file I had

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
```

I tried to remove the `require jquery_ujs` line and now it seems to work until I run the `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` command and restart the server. ***Exactly***: if I remove the `require jquery_ujs` line and I do *not* run the `bundle` command it works as well as expected; but if then I run the `bundle` command the AJAX form submission doesn't work "at all"\"anymore".

*Maybe the problem is related to the `bundle` command that generates fingerprinted files...* could be that?

---

**UPDATE II**

My filesystem related to JavaScript files is:

```
app/assets/javascripts/
app/assets/javascripts/application.js

lib/assets/javascripts/

vendor/assets/javascripts/
vendor/assets/javascripts/vendor.js
vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery_plugins/plugin1.js
vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery_plugins/plugin2.js
vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery_plugins/....js
```

In my `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` file I have:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//
//= require_tree .
//
//= require vendor
```

In my `vendor/assets/javascripts/vendor.js` file I have:

```
//= require_directory ./jquery_plugins
```

If I run the following command

```
$ bundle exec rake assets:precompile
/<MY_USER_PATH>/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby /<MY_USER_PATH>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
/<MY_USER_PATH>/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby /U<MY_USER_PATH>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/rake assets:precompile:nondigest RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
```

in the `public/assets/` directory it creates those files

```
application-b63d5946eebe0c8d46e078ef32299fc5.js
application-b63d5946eebe0c8d46e078ef32299fc5.js.gz
application.js
application.js.gz
manifest.yml
...
```

If I inspect the page HTML code, I can see the following:

```
<script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_plugins/plugin1.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_plugins/plugin2.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_plugins/....js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/vendor.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Do you have a `jquery-ujs.js` file still in your `app/assets/javascripts` folder?

Comment: @Dylan Markow - I updated the question. Can you give me a confirmation if the problem depends on the `require jquery_ujs` line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to Rails 3.1, you would include jQuery-ujs by manually adding `rails.js` to your `public/javascripts` folder.

With Rails 3.1, you now have a `gem 'jquery-rails'` line in your `Gemfile` and a `require jquery_ujs` line in your `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` file; there is no need for manually adding the `rails.js` file because it's already bundled with the gem.

If you upgraded a non-3.1 app to 3.1, you may still have `rails.js` sitting around, so the UJS stuff is getting run twice. Rather than removing the `require` line from your `application.js` file, you should probably just delete the `rails.js` file instead. (You also may still have the actual jQuery JS file sitting in there too; same thing, it's included automatically by the `jquery-rails` gem and you can delete it).

**UPDATE**

I just realized you're precompiling your assets. You don't want to do this in development mode, as when you request `/assets/application.js` it's probably serving up `/public/assets/application.js` which includes all the other JS files inside of it. To fix, clear out the `public/assets` folder and only precompile your assets in production. (See [Rails 3.1 remote requests submitting twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7721502/rails-3-1-remote-requests-submitting-twice))

Comment: I've done a search but none of the files that you have mentioned are in directories of my application. I also updated the question with some more information.

Comment: If I inspect the HTML code I can see that I do *not* have duplicated of any "core" file that you have mentioned in your answer (see the last part of the updated question for more information).

Comment: Just updated my answer, it most likely has to do with precompiling assets in development mode.

Comment: In `development` mode on my local machine, I tried to follow the solution proposed in your linked question (that is: 1. to delete the `public/assets` path at all, 2. to restart my server) but I am still getting the problem. Am I forgetting to do something?

Comment: Just ask the code you want to see and I will update the question. Anyway, thank for your help.