# Rails page loads modal-backdrop twice?

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

When I close the modal (click outside the modal), the webpage is still dark, and I have to click a second time somewhere on the page for it to be normal again. Anyone knows what the problem might be?

**_post_modal.html.erb**

```
<div id="<%= p.id %>" class="modal hide" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <p><h3 id="myModalLabel"><%= p.title %></h3></p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <%= raw(p.link) %>
    </div>
</div>
```

**_single_post.html.erb**

```
<% @posts.each do |p| %>
   <%= render "post_modal" %> 
<% end %>
```

**list.html.erb**

```
<div class="container">
   <%= render 'single_post' %>
</div>
```

**application.html.erb**

```
<body>
    <%= link_to('Logout user', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete) %>
    <%= link_to('Logout admin', destroy_admin_session_path, :method => :delete) %>
    <%= yield %>
</body>
```

**custom.css.scss**

```
body{
      background-image:url('dark_leather.png');
      color: #333;
      font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
      line-height: 18px;
}

.container{
    vertical-align: center;
}

.modal{
    h3{
        font-family: 'Josefin Slab', serif;
        font-size: 18pt;
        font-weight: 400;
        color: #34DDDD;
    }
}
```

Comment: So I found out (from the "Inspect Element" in Chrome), that the page opens up two `<div class="modal backdrop  in"></div>`, instead of just one. This is the reason I have to click twice to make the dark overlay disapear. So how can I make it just open once (instead of two)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of googleing and reading, I found a solution.

I first found [this](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/679), that lead me to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170039/ruby-on-rails-3-1-assets-pipeline-assets-rendered-twice), that lead me to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7721502/rails-3-1-remote-requests-submitting-twice/7854902#7854902). (Useful because it gives alternative solutions and explanations).

**In short:**

**1)** First I added this: `config.serve_static_assets = false` to my `config/environments/development.rb` file.

**2)** Then I ran the `rake assets:clean` command in terminal.

**3)** And finally i deleted the cache in my browser.

It worked - and why it worked, is a long explanation written in the links above ;)

Answer (score 3):

Hide the modal before doing the ajax request. I had the same problem and that solved it. With me it was more of an issue of replacing the container that contained the actual modal window.

If that doesn't work you can always force it to go away by doing the following:

```
$('#your-modal-id').modal('hide');
$('body').removeClass('modal-open');
$('.modal-backdrop').remove();
```

Comment: Hi Vector, thanks for your answer, but what do you mean with "Hide the modal before doing the ajax request"? How can I do this?

Comment: Vector, you just copied this answer...(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11519660/twitter-bootstrap-modal-backdrop-doesnt-disappear)